# Android expandable grid of buttons

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox, grid

So, in my application I have a grid of buttons. Each one is set to `addView(closedVies)` and then `removeView(openView)` if one was displayed. The views that I'm adding contain several checkboxes and on each checkbox I will be setting an onClickListener as well.

I have it working my way, but is there an easier or more efficient way it could be done?

There will be a background behind the checkboxes that will connect to whichever button opened it. I have that figured out just haven't implemented it yet.

The checkboxes are in a linearlayout defined in XML

From Samsung mobile

Here is basically what it will look like:

[image]

Comment: I have a LinearLayout as the Outer View, then that contains a ScrollView, which then contains a RelativeLayout, which contains four LinearLayouts. Each inner LinearLayout contains 3 Buttons with a horizontal orientation so the buttons can be the same size. But, more simply, each button is within a LinearLayout, which I think is what matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of projects from Romain Guy. There is a project named PhotoStream that uses a GridLayout. This is sort of like the LinearLayout but we specify the number to rows and columns. So the childs to this layout are automatically laid out as a grid. Its a good alternative to what you have done so far.

[Here is the link to the project.](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/). This is the link for the [gridlayout](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/GridLayout.java). I recommend you checkout the project and take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, but the laying of my buttons in the grid isn't really the issue. My concern is more of expanding the new LinearLayout with the CheckBoxes.

Comment: can you put your xml code up. It will be more easy to figure if it can be optimized.

Comment: I actually am satisfied with the way it operates now, otherwise I would post some code. Thank you for your help.